# Capture Images every 5 seconds in Camera

Tags: java, android, camera

When i click the button ,I want an callback to capture again every 5 seconds. this is my code

but when i try to click again the camera is not shown.

```
 private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Handler myHandler = new Handler();
         myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 5000); // called after 5 seconds
         button.setText("Waiting...");
     }};
```

Comment: you current code will trigger only one time. If you wish to trigger it every 5 sec then use `Timer`. And I don't see any Camera related code in your click method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no certain timer programmatically for the Camera . so the best thing is that you should create a thread for the camera Action and then repeat that thread after 5 seconds
Your code will trigger only one time ... so what you have to do is that after creation of thread call that thread on button click and the thread will run automatically....

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
runnable.run();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{

    public void run() 
    {
         //
         // Do the stuff
         //

         handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: What should i put in the run?

Comment: you should call the method here which capture the camera image ... and set 1000 timer to 5000 for 5 seconds

Comment: just call the method which do the functionality